# 400 Bad Request Error from ajax to Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

Url is not going to jsp ajax call to controller. The following ajax call function is not going to controller. It has showing 400 Bad Request error.

```js
if (updateList.length != 0) {    
    isoffhireUpdated = "Y";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i].name = data[i]["name"];
        data[i].relationship = data[i]["relationship"];
        data[i].dateOfBirth = data[i]["dateOfBirth"];
        data[i].maritalStatus = data[i]["maritalStatus"];
        data[i].gender = data[i]["gender"];
        data[i].address = data[i]["address"];
    }
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    url: "dependencyDetailsSave",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        $('div.jGrowl').find('div.jGrowl-notification').parent().remove();
        $.jGrowl("Data was Successfully Saved", {
            sticky: false
        });
        $("#dependency_details").pqGrid("refreshDataAndView");
    }
});
```

This is my controller class function.

```js
@RequestMapping(value = "/dependencyDetailsSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public int dependencyDetailsSave(@RequestBody List<DependencyMasterDetails> obj, Model model,HttpSession session)throws IOException, Exception {
    int offhireupdateResult = 0; 
    offhireupdateResult = profileService.changeOffhireValueUpdate(obj);       
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to verify the fields in `DependencyMasterDetails` class and fields in `JSON` that you pass from `AJAX`.

Most of the time it happens ,if there is mismatch(name) of fields between `Front end`(AJAX) and `Back end`(JAVA).

All the fields you are passing from `AJAX` ,must be present in `DependencyMasterDetails` class,with same name,unless you are explicitly ignoring them (`@JsonIgnore`).